# SAPUI5 - Get the list of Supplier based on the product

Tags: sapui5

I have tried using below code but it is giving the list of all the supplier

[image: Here is what i have done]

---

```
<ObjectPageSection title="Suppliers">
            <subSections>
                <ObjectPageSubSection>
                    <blocks>
                        <m:Table id="suppliersTable" items="{path : 'products>/Products' , parameters:{expand : 'Supplier'} }">
                            <m:columns>
                                <m:Column/>
                            </m:columns>
                            <m:items>
                                <m:ColumnListItem >
                                    <m:cells>
                                        <m:ObjectIdentifier text="{products>Supplier/Name}"/>
                                    </m:cells>
                                </m:ColumnListItem>
                            </m:items>
                        </m:Table>
                    </blocks>
                </ObjectPageSubSection>
            </subSections>
        </ObjectPageSection>
```

I used Northwind [OData service -](http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/Products)

I want only those supplier related to the product 
like below:

[Supplier1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nkCv.png) and [Supplier2](http://services.odata.org/V2/OData/OData.svc/Products(6)/Supplier)

Can anyone please help me.

Comment: How are you navigating to this page ? You should bind the element you desire to the view to then access its properties. Say you select an item with ID 6. Navigate to the details view and send the id to it. Bind the element Products(6) and all your databindings will reference that product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by binding the element to the view on your controller (place this on your handleRouteMatched method):

```
        var self = this;
        var argsId = oEvent.getParameters().data.Id;
        var view = self.getView();
        var yourTable = view.byId("suppliersTable");
        yourTable.bindElement({
            path: "products>/Products('" + argsId + "')",
            parameters: { expand: "Supplier" },
            events: {
                dataRequested: function () {
                    self.getView().setBusy(true);
                    //some error handling logic you might want
                },
                dataReceived: function () {
                    self.getView().setBusy(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

This will make all your bindings on the table relative to the Product that triggered the navigation. Your view code will then look like this:

```
<ObjectPageSection title="Suppliers">
            <subSections>
                <ObjectPageSubSection>
                    <blocks>
                        <m:Table id="suppliersTable">
                            <m:columns>
                                <m:Column/>
                            </m:columns>
                            <m:items>
                                <m:ColumnListItem >
                                    <m:cells>
                                        <m:ObjectIdentifier text="{products>Supplier/Name}"/>
                                    </m:cells>
                                </m:ColumnListItem>
                            </m:items>
                        </m:Table>
                    </blocks>
                </ObjectPageSubSection>
            </subSections>
        </ObjectPageSection>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have set navigation in manifest.json

```
    "routing": {
        "config": {
            "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
            "viewType": "XML",
            "viewPath": "Product.view",
            "controlId": "app",
            "controlAggregation": "pages"
        },
        "routes": [{
            "pattern": "",
            "name": "productList",
            "target": "productList"
        }, {
            "pattern": "detail/{productsData}/Supplier",
            "name": "detail",
            "target": "detail"
        }],
        "targets": {
            "productList": {
                "viewName": "ProductList"
            },
            "detail": {
                "viewName": "Detail"
            }
        }
    }
```

I am navigating from ProductList page to Details page 
[ProductList Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXbov.png)